# ClassCastException While Create an org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo Instance (Apache POI)

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im trying to add protection into a MS Excel File using Apache POI, It was working fine while I was making some tests but when I proved the functionality at runtime in Weblogic Server 12 it fails. Here is my code:

---

```
public static void parseFileToSecureFile(String fullFileName, String password) throws MyException{
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    EncryptionInfo info =
        new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes256, HashAlgorithm.sha512, -1, -1, null);
    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
    enc.confirmPassword(password);
    OPCPackage opc = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(fullFileName), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
        os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
        opc.save(os);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fullFileName);
        fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error: "+e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new MyException("An Error");
    }finally {
         fs.close();
         fos.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Inicia");
    try {
        parseFileToSecureFile("/my_path/my_file.xlsx", "11");
    } catch (MyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finaliza");

}
```

---

As I told you, if I run my code "As-Is" from my "main method" it works, but if i invoke the method from a web application at runtime, I have the next Exception:

---

```
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.agile.AgileEncryptionInfoBuilder cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfoBuilder
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:186)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:153)
    at com.tets.test.test.FileCipher.parserFileToSecureFile(FileCipher.java:39)
    at com.test.test.test.backing.MyAdmin.doSomething(Something.java:387)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding(UIXComponentBase.java:1988)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXEditableValue.broadcast(UIXEditableValue.java:257)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeApplyValidateOrUpdate(LifecycleImpl.java:642)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:370)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:227)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.sky.osm.view.FilterSession.doFilter(FilterSession.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

---

Thank you by your help

Comment: Remove the old Apache POI jars from your runtime classpath! As per [the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html), mixing old and new jars won't work!

Comment: Thank You by your Answear **Gagravarr**

Comment: Thank You by your Answear **Gagravarr**

Currently, I'm Using the poi, poi-excelant, poi-ooxml and poi-ooxml-schemas libraries all of them at 3.15 version.

However, i see at the link you post I should use the ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar version, I will try to apply this change and provide you some feedback

Kind regards

Comment: Hello **Gagravarr**

Finally I resolve the problem Upgrading my POI jar Version to the newest version Avalible (4.0.1)

Thank You By Your Help

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else have the same problem, this is the change i had to do:

- Update my POI version from v3.15 to v4.0.1
- Add the commons-compress v1.18

Additionally if you have to read the crypted file, you will need:

- xmlbeans-3.0.2
- commons-collections4-4.1

Weblogic Server has his own xmlbeans version and you will have a dependency conflict, so, you will need to add to your weblogic.xml file the next tag in the container descriptor tag:

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

You will need to add the next tags to the weblogic-application.xml file too:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.xmlbeans.*</package-name>
        <package-name>repackage.*</package-name>
        <package-name>schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.*</package-name>
 </prefer-application-packages>
```